# How to pluck fields from a distant relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, parsing, foreign-keys

I have a many to one relationship for getting each product its images, every product should have a lot of images to view it to user.
so I tried to get stocks with images
when I do

```
 public function getImages() {
        $stocks = Stocks::with('images', 'tags')->get();
        return $stocks;
    }
```

it returns this

```
[
   {
       "id": 7,
       "name": "1",
       "descriptions": "1",
       "price": 1,
       "discount": 1,
       "category": "new",
       "quantity": 1,
       "brand": "1",
       "created_at": "2019-08-04 09:07:25",
       "updated_at": "2019-08-04 09:07:25",
       "images": [
           {
               "id": 6,
               "url": "1564909645iKiw2LkoEcQIIhB4MTZJTUfwTREleWH4wEuvmRPd.png",
               "created_at": "2019-08-04 09:07:25",
               "updated_at": "2019-08-04 09:07:25",
               "pivot": {
                   "stocks_id": 7,
                   "images_id": 6
               }
           },
           {
               "id": 7,
               "url": "1564909645OVxnM0qmoQayZrP7wq82pTmSj1AwQc9gioyC5L7h.png",
               "created_at": "2019-08-04 09:07:25",
               "updated_at": "2019-08-04 09:07:25",
               "pivot": {
                   "stocks_id": 7,
                   "images_id": 7
               }
           }
       ],
       "tags": [
           {
               "id": 1,
               "tag": "عطور",
               "created_at": "2019-08-03 17:45:52",
               "updated_at": "2019-08-03 17:45:52",
               "pivot": {
                   "stocks_id": 7,
                   "tag_id": 1
               }
           }
       ]
   }
]
```

but I want **"images"** to have only urls as strings like:

```
"images":[1.png,2.png,3.png .....]
```

what should I do?

my relation

```
public function images()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Images', 'stock_images');
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to return that structure as json to an http response or do you have to do more processing on this data?

Comment: json to an http response for flutter app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want "images" to have only urls as strings like:
>
> ```
> "images":[1.png,2.png,3.png .....]
> ```
>
> what should I do?

The quickest solution would be to add the `$visible` property to your `App\Images` model, like so:

```php
public $visible = ['url'];
```

This will remove all the fields from the json, including the `pivot` field, except for those defined in the `visible` property. This solution works fine but it still selects all columns from the images table, if you want it to select only the minimum required fields (so you improve performance) for the relation, you can do:

```php
$stocks = Stocks::with('images:url', 'tags')->get(); // this is a shortcut for selecting only url
```

Please, be aware that the solution above works fine for ManyToMany (N:N) relationships. However, for a hasMany (1:N), you'd have to select the primary key and all related foreign keys as well.

Hope it helps.

References:

[Eloquent: Relationships#Eager-Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

### UPDATE

> It worked but how can I remove the key url: and store only values 1,2,3

`->pluck()` is the collection function to do that, however, you can't easily pluck fields from a distant relationship without discarding the rest, but this macro will do the trick.

### `->pluckDistant()`

In your `AppServiceProvider`, under the `boot` method, add this macro function:

```php
public function boot()
{
    /**
     * Shortcut to pluck a field in a relationship.
     *
     * @param string $relationship The relationship name
     * @param string|array $value
     * @param string|null $key
     */
    collect()->macro('pluckDistant', function($relationship, $value, $key = null) {
        return $this->map(function($item) use($relationship, $value, $key) {
            $relation = $item->getRelation($relationship);

            if (get_class($relation) == \Illuminate\Support\Collection::class ||
                get_class($relation) == \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::class) {
                $item->setRelation($relationship, $relation->pluck($value, $key));
            }

            return $item;
        });
    });
}
```

And then, you do this:

```php
$stocks = Stocks::with('images:url', 'tags')->get()->pluckDistant('images', 'url');
```

Comment: It worked but how can I remove the key **url:** and store only values **1,2,3** ?

Comment: I updated the answer for you, please upvote and if it works for you, accept it, hope it does :)

Comment: It worked!!!! thanks a lot but is this going to affect the performance badly and make slow response?

Comment: Not at all, since you are eager loading the relation.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure when eager loading relationships with the function `with()`.

In that closure you can use the select function to filter columns.

```php
$stocks = Stock::with('tags')
              ->with(['images' => function ($query) {
                  $query->select(['id', 'url']);
              }])
              ->get();
```

**UPDATE**

If you want only the values without keys, you cannot use this approach. You have to do it after fetching the data from the database. like this..

```php
$stocks = Stock::with('images', 'tags')->get()->map(function ($stock) {
    $stock->images = $stock->images->map->url->values();

    $stock->unsetRelation('images');

    return $stock;
});
```

Comment: how can I get only values without keys?

Comment: We need to go with different approach I guess. I updated the answer.

Comment: It returns only this:
````[
    [
        "1564909645iKiw2LkoEcQIIhB4MTZJTUfwTREleWH4wEuvmRPd.png",
        "1564909645OVxnM0qmoQayZrP7wq82pTmSj1AwQc9gioyC5L7h.png"
    ]
]
````
I want the other data as well

Comment: Ok I think there was mistake. Try the new updated answer.

Comment: It returned back to keys and values

Comment: Keys and values? you mean like `images : [ 'url' => '1.png' ]`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your query like this:

```
$stocks = Stock::with(['tags','images' => function ($query) {
              $query->get()->pluck('url');
          }])->get();
```

Comment: I think this is wrong. We cannot call `get()` inside a query builder. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are you sure? if not try it please.

Comment: I only want the values without keys

Comment: @MohammedAktaa Yes I tried. And also you don't have to try if you clearly understand what '`laravel query builder` is and how it works.